# Cryptographically hashing a tree of elements

Tags: hash, cryptography, rsa, sha256

I am working on a project where I have a tree of objects. This tree of objects can be quite large, and can be subject to very frequent modifications (e.g. adding or removing a node, changing some properties of a node, and so on) by more users. Now, every time an update is published by an user, I need to be able to get some hash of the tree as it is after the user modified it, so that the user can sign the update with his private RSA key. Therefore I obviously need the hash to be cryptographically secure. However, hashing a linear representation of the whole tree over and over every time an user changes just one node is unfeasible.

I thought about this strategy, but I am not sure if that will work out properly:

- I add to each node of a new field, that is the SHA256 hash of all its children nodes.
- The hash of a node is now the hash of each of the fields of the node, therefore included the hash of its children.

Now, updating the tree should be easy: every time I update a node, I change the hash field of its parent, then it's grandparent and so on until the root is reached, and use the hash of the root as hash value. This would reduce the complexity of this operation to O(ln(N)) rather than O(N).

However, I know that it is never safe to trust one's own intuition about cryptography. So is this procedure secure?

Comment: It seems reasonably reliable as far as your explanation goes.  However, how are you generating the hash of a leaf node?  Are nodes sufficiently "different" from each other that their hashes will be well distributed?  For example if your nodes are a 3D coordinate and most points tend to be close to the origin, you can run into problems of sufficient distribution.  Also, how are you combining leaf node hashes to form the parent node hash?

Comment: It sounds like you're already deep into implementing completely custom crypto which is more than likely to be broken in some way. Why is it 'obvious' you need a cryptographically secure hash of something you're going to sign cryptographically? Why is it 'unfeasable' to hash the tree? Are you sure you're avoiding 'length extension' problems? Etc

Comment: @EricJ. I definitely have to think about how to hash leaf nodes. However, every single node is completely different from the other. They are long sequences of bytes that never repeat.

Comment: In that case, a SHA256 hash of those bytes should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a [hash tree or Merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree). It's nothing new and it is secure. It is often used to parallelize hashing as the hash methods themselves are strictly sequential in nature.

Don't concatenate data and hashes though unless you explicitly include the size of the data. It's better to only concatenate hashes.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your algorithm is already good enough.

Assuming that SHA-256 is secure (well, at least, its name is "Secure Hash Algorithm"), one can prove, by induction on the depth of the tree, that your algorithm is secure as well.

Comment: I agree. Data are data.